# How to store my results into another array?

Tags: java, arrays

i want to store the averages that i got from a 2D array into a 1D array. Im unsure how to do so!

```
package javaprogram;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class program {



    public static void main(String[] args) {


         //a one-dimensional array to store the student names
        String names[] = {"Johnson","Aniston","Cooper","Gupta",
            "Blair","Clark","Kennedy","Bronson","Sunny", "smith"};

        // a 2 dimentional array to store scores
        int[][] scores =  { {85, 83, 77, 91,76}, {80,90,95,93,48},
        {78,81,11,90,73},{92,83,30,69,87}, {23,45,96,38,59}, {60,85,45,39,67},
        {77,31,52,74,83}, {93,94,89,77,97},{79,85,28,93,82},{85,72,49,75,63}};

        //a 1 dimentional array to store grades
        double[] grade = new double[10];


        double sum=0, average=0;


        for(int row=0; row<10; row++)
        {
            sum = 0;

            for(int col=0; col<scores[row].length; col++)
            {
                sum = sum +scores[row][col];
                average= sum/5;

            }

            System.out.println(average);

        }



    }

}
```

Comment: I want the averages to be added to the grade array. Basically my loops get the average grades of each row and i wan these averages to go into grade array.

Comment: Grade[row]=average after second for but inside first for

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
double[] grade = new double[10];
double sum=0, average=0;

for(int row=0; row<10; row++) {
    sum = 0;
    for(int col=0; col<scores[row].length; col++){
        sum += scores[row][col];
    }
    average = sum/5;
    grade[row] = average;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make this modification

1. take out `average= sum/5;` outside the inner loop
2. store it in your 1D array each rows average `grade[row] = sum/5;`

```
 for(int row=0; row<10; row++)
    {
        sum = 0;    
        for(int col=0; col<scores[row].length; col++)
        {
            sum = sum +scores[row][col];   
        }

       grade[row] = sum/5;   // store it in your array each rows average      
        System.out.println(grade[row]);    
    }
```

note that since all your scores are `int`, you will get integer average not decimal average.